# How to read guarded id field of model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel 6 project there is a model with guarded id field:

```
class Customer extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use SoftDeletes, RevisionableTrait, TransformableTrait;

    protected $table      = 'customers';
    protected $guarded    = ['id'];
```

and creating new customer with factory, I see null id field value:

```
$NewCustomer     = factory(Customer::class)->make();
\Log::info( '-99 $NewCustomer->id ::' . print_r( $NewCustomer->id, true  
) ); // THIS value is null
```

How to read id value of $NewCustomer ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make only creates an object but does not save it to the database. Therefore you do not get an id.

The primary key will be auto-incremented in the database, so you only know the id after you save the object.

[Creating Models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#creating-models)

If you want to save automatically you can also directly use the save function:

```
$NewCustomer = factory(Customer::class)->create();
```

This work the same as:

```
$newCustomer = factory(Customer::class)->make();
$newCustomer->save();
```

[Persisting Models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#persisting-models)

Also guarded is only a security feature for mass-assignment and prevents saving the id row on those.

[Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Oh , I have to use create method ?

Comment: If you want to create a persistent database entry, than you have to create it with `create()`. You can also use `save()` after using `make()` to create a database entry.

Comment: Yes. If you use the default settings for primary key, it will be autoincremented in the database, so you only have it after you save it.